# KML file not showing correct location and polygon orientation. Syntax issue?

Tags: kml, google-earth

Hi I wrote a Javascript to output a KML file based on a polygon area marked on google maps api v3. The file used to worked correctly, showed the right location and polygon shape on Google Earth Pro

Now suddenly instead of showing the London Eye area in London it shows an area in Congo and the polygon doesnt even appear correctly on google earth. I tried to debug it appears that the coordinate seems to be causing the problem. However, when i save it to MyPlaces on google maps online it parses the KML and shows the shape and location properly. Thanks for your help. KML Below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
<name>test</name><description>test</description>
<Style id='style1'>
<LineStyle>
<width>5</width>
  </LineStyle>
<PolyStyle>
<color>0FF00000</color>
<fill>1</fill>
 <outline>1</outline>
 </PolyStyle>
 </Style>
<Placemark>
 <name>?</name>
<styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
<Polygon>
<outerBoundaryIs>
 <LinearRing>
 <tessellate>1</tessellate>
<coordinates>
51.50519078602326, -0.12681582942195746, 
51.50708732603467, -0.12381175532527777, 
51.50553804573176, -0.1123104430694184, 
51.50166461450478, -0.11462787165828558, 
51.50519078602326, -0.12681582942195746, 
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your KML is invalid, and Google Earth is no longer as permissive as it was in accepting this type of invalid coordinates.

Specifically, you have an extra comma at end of each line in your KML -- so just remove them, or else add the optional altitude value after them.

Also remove the whitespace between the separate parts of the coordinate. Your coordinates will now be converted to three separate coordinates by Google Earth:
51.50519078602326,0,0 and -0.12681582942195746,0,0 and 0,0,0.

Change it to:
51.50519078602326,-0.12681582942195746,0
51.50708732603467,-0.12381175532527777,0

Or:
51.50519078602326,-0.12681582942195746
51.50708732603467,-0.12381175532527777

See https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#polygons for a polygon example or the  section and https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linearring for extra details.

Comment: @Leon: perhaps your edit should have been an answer in its own right. I hit _accept_ because it looks too useful to lose, but others might _reject_. You should get credit for it...